# Vuejs3, Vite - How to run Production Build

Tags: npm, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to run a simple vue.js app. My setup is a vue.js 3 app with vite, built according to the tutorial on the official website. (https://vitejs.dev/guide/#command-line-interface)
Now I try to deploy that on a cloud and I need the command to run the app. I don't find any information about that. My package.json is lacking the entry for start or run. I don't find any information about the command on the official website. What am I missing?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-vite-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.5",
    "postcss": "^8.3.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.15",
    "vite": "^1.0.0-rc.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens after you run `npm build`? Any console messages?

Comment: We need more information about your deployment environment. You mention cloud, but are you trying to run in a static S3 bucket in AWS, a container somewhere, etc?  ```npm run build``` will create the distributable needed to run the app, but we need to know where you are trying to publish the app.

Answer (score 20):

You can do it with preview.  [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#testing-the-app-locally)

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

then

```
$ npm run build
$ npm run preview
```

Comment: It is important to note that vite preview is intended for previewing the build locally and not meant as a production server. https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#testing-the-app-locally:~:text=It%20is%20important%20to%20note%20that%20vite%20preview%20is%20intended%20for%20previewing%20the%20build%20locally%20and%20not%20meant%20as%20a%20production%20server.

Comment: @user2704504 What should I use for serving the application as a production server?

Comment: @PéterSzilvási you can go for any static server https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#deploying-a-static-site

Comment: `npm run preview` is not meant for production, it is there so that you can test your build locally.

Comment: for prod use $ npm run build

Answer (score 3):

According to the official docs, "vite build" will create the prod build using your index.html file as entry point. You can also specify another publich patch. [Check it out](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview"
},
```

now use:

```
$ npm run build
```

It will create a static file: `index.html` (by default in a `dist` folder in root - this location can be changed. refer [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-outdir)). **Then you can deploy this static file.**

Please refer:

1. Building for production: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build
2. Deploying a Static Site: https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy

Note: You may have used `vite preview` (`npm run preview`) as it loads faster than using `npm run dev`. But it is important to note that `vite preview` is intended for previewing the build locally and not meant as a production server. It's an easy way to check if the production build looks OK in your local environment.

Comment: As an aside, `npm run build` also works from _within_ the container in Docker, via the Exec tab, whereas `vite build` won't, at least not for me.